# Kivy button: how to assign on_press command defined in another function within same class

Tags: python, button, kivy

I should probably start by saying I am an absolute beginner with Python and Kivy, so please excuse me if the question is very naive.

I am trying to get a Kivy button to run a command on_press. The command is defined in another function which belongs to the same class. However, I always get the following error:

> self.searchButton.bind(on_press=self.searchRecipe())
>   File "kivy_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
>   AssertionError: None is not callable

I have already looked at similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541667/error-while-binding-functions-to-buttons-in-a-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208224/how-to-call-a-function-with-on-press-command-inside-same-class-using-kivy-butt)) but still could not figure out what I am doing wrong.

I should also add that, for the sake of learning, I do not want to use .kv files at the moment, but include everything in my python script. After getting a nice understanding of it, I will try to migrate some parts to a .kv file.

Below is a minimal (non-working) example. Of course the searchRecipe function should do more than just printing (connect to a SQLite db and perform some other stuff), but this is just a tryout.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class RootWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(RootWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)     
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        self.searchButton = Button(text="Search")
        self.searchButton.bind(on_press=self.searchRecipe())                                  
        self.add_widget(self.searchButton)

    def searchRecipe(self):
        print("It works!")

class RecipApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RecipApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.searchButton.bind(on_press=self.searchRecipe())
```

`self.searchRecipe()` evaluates to None. You want `self.searchButton.bind(on_press=self.searchRecipe)`.

Comment: when I do this, I get:
TypeError: searchRecipe() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: ADD: I get this second error when actually pressing the button, not at runtime (like in the original code)

Comment: That's because the clock function call passes the time since the scheduling as an argument.

Comment: Excuse me but, I don't really understand what you mean. What should I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Your error is that `searchRecipe` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Make it accept a second positional argument, i.e. `def searchRecipe(self, the_second_positional_argument):`